# action setting bar not displyed in handphone

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to ask about action bar in my apps, on picture below action setting bar is displyed on emulator like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisBw.jpg

but when i try to my handphone with os v4.2.2(Jellybean)
that action setting is blank, see picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiRiv.png

what wrong with the apps, please help to solve this problem.thanks

Comment: Your phone probably has a menu button. Android won't display the options icon if you have a menu button on your phone.

Comment: you mean back button on my handphone?